# Is there a way to update a JSON key if it already exists and create a key if doesn't on Redis with Node Redis OM

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

I have a schema that contains a `discord` field, it stores the user discord user id.

I want to create a JSON key if none of the existing keys match the `discord` key that I'm going to create, but update the key that the `discord` field matches. I'm using Redis OM for Node.js but there's barely any documentation that clearly tells me what I can do.

Here's my current code

```
export async function createStudent(data: StudentData): Promise<string> {
  await connect();

  const repository = client.fetchRepository(schema);

  const student = repository.createEntity(data);

  const id = await repository.save(student);

  await client.execute(["EXPIRE", `Student:${id}`, 60]);

  return id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in functionality in Redis to do this, but you could write a custom script to do it.
something like this:

```
    if (redis.exists(key)) {
    
    redis.hset(key, field, value);
    
    } else {
    
    redis.hset(key, field, value);
    
    redis.expire(key, 60);
    
    }
```